# Error while executing batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

This is my first time creating a batch file. I am trying to execute by adding all the following inside a batch file. however the flow stops at the for loop. these command works when directly executed on command prompt. And I am also facing error with the copy command

```
SET ROOT="C:\Rahul\Projects\sub-folder"

SET WEB1=%ROOT%\folder1\1.war
SET WEB2=%ROOT%\folder2\2.war

SET SOURCE=%WEB1% %WEB2% 

SET TARGET=C:\Rahul\softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\

c:
cd C:\Rahul\softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.29
rmdir /q /s work\Catalina
cd webapps

FOR %i in ("*.war") do rmdir /q /s  %~ni
FOR %i in ("*.war") do del /q /s  %i
FOR %i in (%SOURCE%) do copy %i %TARGET%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR %i in ("*.war") do rmdir /q /s  %~ni` will work in the command line but not in a batch. Inside a batch file you must replace `%i` with `%%i`. This should be it.

Comment: I am also facing problem with the copy command as my folder have space in between them the last for loop is considering as different items.

Comment: Surround your variables with quotes: FOR %%i in (%SOURCE%) do copy "%%i" "%TARGET%"

Comment: got it i replace `SET WEB1="%ROOT%\folder1\1.war"`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is more often easier to not use quoting in the `SET` statement. Then, use quoting whenever it is used.

```
SET THEVAR=C:\Program Files
DIR "%THEVAR%\Common Files"
```

Comment: If i do not use the quote it converts the space between folder names as an another variable causing inconsistency within array `SOURCE`

Comment: You are right, @RahulThachilath. However `SOURCE` does not represent a single file or directory name. I my experience, it would be more clear to use `FOR %i in ("%WEB1%" "%WEB2%") do ...`